# tornado - object memory disposing

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, tornado

I am developing web applications using tornado, pandas, numpy modules.

After requests are processed, the memory size of this application increases and never goes down.

I think the allocated memory for "PrintInfo" class isn't disposed.

How can I handle this situation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is sample code.

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-'
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class PrintInfo:
    def PrintDataFrame(self, _df):
        print _df.head()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        randn = np.random.randn
        testDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(randn( 1000000 , 100 ))

        save=PrintInfo()
        save.PrintDataFrame(testDataFrame)

        self.write("Done!!")
        self.finish()

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [ (r"/", MainHandler), ]
        settings = dict(debug=True)
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen( 9999 )
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following lines after `self.finish()`.

```
del testDataFrame
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: @hyry will  gc.collect() block event loop ? I don't know how to test this